# How do I create a clock using Timer?

Tags: java, swing, timer

I am trying to create a seven segment display that automatically moves using the timer with the use of the ActionListener and actionPerformed.

I thought that if I use the for, if statement it would automatically loop from 0 to 2 and set the Background color for each segment of the numbers. However, when I display it, it is stuck on just displaying zero and will not count up from there.

Can anyone help me on what I am doing wrong, that makes this stuck on zero?

Here is the programming I have now using JFrame.

```java
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class SevenSegment extends JFrame {
Timer timer = new Timer(100, null);

public SevenSegment() {
timer.start();

        timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    if(i == 0) {
                        lblNumberOne.setBackground(Color.red);
                        lblNumberTwo.setBackground(Color.red);
                        lblNumberThree.setBackground(Color.red);
                        lblNumberFour.setBackground(Color.red);
                        lblNumberFive.setBackground(Color.red);
                        lblNumberSix.setBackground(Color.red);
                    }
                    else if(i == 1) {
                        lblNumberTwo.setBackground(Color.red);
                        lblNumberThree.setBackground(Color.red);
                    }
                    else if(i == 2) {
                        lblNumberOne.setBackground(Color.red);
                        lblNumberTwo.setBackground(Color.red);
                
                    }
                        
                    
                }

          } 
            
        });
        
     }
}
```

Comment: After `i==0` all the backgrounds are red; then in `i ==1` you set two to red - the remainder stay red.  So not sure what you are expecting; seems like you'll need to `setBackground` for all labels each time to see changes.

Comment: Hello Andy, now I understand. Thank you!

Comment: *"(Using Java and Eclipse)"* There is no need to mention any of the major tags in the title. There is no need to mention the IDE unless the code works in another IDE.

Comment: You are doing everything in one iteration of the Timer ActionListener.  You only do one thing at a time.l

Answer (score 3):

Here's about as simple a Swing GUI clock as you can make.

[image: Clock GUI]

I did this so I could show you a general way to start all of your Swing GUIs.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html), that will show you how to create all kinds of Swing GUIs.

We start all Swing GUIs with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that all Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

We always create a `JPanel` to put our Swing components on.  The only Swing component that we add to a `JFrame` is a `JPanel` or a `JScrollPane`.  This allows us to separate the creation of a `JFrame` from the rest of the view. The `JFrame` code is nearly identical for all Swing applications.  The only difference is the `JPanels` you add to the `JFrame`.

The `JFrame` code must be called in a specific order.  This is the order I use for my Swing applications.

The `JPanel` code is in a separate paragraph for general tidiness.  I like to keep things separate so I can focus on one small part of the GUI at a time.

The `updateClockLabel` method exists because I need to execute the code one time when I'm creating the `JPanel`, and five times a second thereafter, to actually update the `JLabel`.

By the way, I didn't write all this code (all 64 lines) in one shot.  I wrote a little, tested a lot.  My code was not correct the first time I wrote it, and I don't just mean making typos.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class SimpleClock implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new SimpleClock());
    }
    
    private JLabel clockLabel;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Clock");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        Timer timer = new Timer(200, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                updateClockLabel();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }
    
    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 45, 5, 45));
        
        clockLabel = new JLabel(" ");
        clockLabel.setFont(panel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 72f));
        updateClockLabel();
        panel.add(clockLabel);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    public void updateClockLabel() {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm:ss a");
        String timeDisplay = LocalTime.now().format(formatter);
        clockLabel.setText(timeDisplay);
    }

}
```